# How to get text from message text box?

Tags: java, java-me, netbeans6.8, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I'm developing mobile application in netbeans and for my application i have to get text from write message box, but i don't know how to get text from message label of sms composer component of netbeans? please help me..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to gain access to *private variable* `message` in the class `SMSComposer` from outside of the class, it just defeats the java OOPS concepts. You might be wishing for *Reflection* support in Java ME but rest assure its NOT supported.

So another approach to your problem would be to recreate a class similar to netbeans `SMSComposer` class and use it the way you like.

You might want to glance through these sites

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-p2pmsg/
2. http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wma/
3. http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/03/send-text-message-sms-using-wireless.html
4. http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/f7600470-fc56-4e1c-8c5c-4441c49cb9bf/Nokia_SMS_API_v0.9.zip.html

Comment: @ShumailaMalik, was this answer helpful for your question ?